# What is meant by "XML-based (TYPO3-custom XML format) label parsing"?

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

In the changelog of TYPO3 v11.0 it lists:

> The following features have been removed:
>
> - XML-based (TYPO3-custom XML format) label parsing

What was the purpose of this feature and how could you use it?

https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/11.0/Breaking-91473-DeprecatedFunctionalityRemoved.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Early days of TYPO3 Translation where handled in an TYPO3 specific XML format. But some time ago TYPO3 switched to XLIFF a standarized XML format.

And i guess this just means the old format is no longer supported.

Comment: Correct, the deprecation got some more information https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/10.1/Deprecation-89037-DeprecatedLocallangXmlParser.html